# create global Axios configuration and add it to the Vue instance

Tags: vue.js, axios

I added Axios to my Vue app via Vue UI dependency installation. I would like to access Axios within my components by using

`this.$http.myHTTPmethod`

So I created **http.js** based on this documentation

https://github.com/axios/axios#axioscreateconfig

```
import axios from "axios";

const devInstance = createInstance("http://localhost:3000");
const productionInstance = createInstance("http://localhost:3000"); // will change later

function createInstance(baseURL){
    return axios.create({
        baseURL,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${localStorage.token}`
        }
    });
}

export default devInstance; // Check debug/build mode
```

My question:

How can I make axios use this axios instance? And how can I access this instance via `this.$http` like I would do with the Vue-Router (`this.$router`)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could make a plugin:

```
import axios from "axios";
import Vue from 'vue'

const devInstance = createInstance("http://localhost:3000");
const productionInstance = createInstance("http://localhost:3000"); // will change later

function createInstance(baseURL){
    return axios.create({
        baseURL,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${localStorage.token}`
        }
    });
}

export default {
    install () {
        Vue.prototype.$http = devInstance
    }
}; // Check debug/build mode
```

And then your plugin into your `main.js` file, before creating your main Vue instance just like this:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import http from './plugins/http.js'

Vue.use(http)
...
```

By doing this, you will have access to your `axios` instance from your components using `this.$http`